# Closing a prettyPhoto lightbox from inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prettyphoto

Would like to run some Javascript in the iFrame which changes the height and width of the prettyPhoto lightbox window that it is in.

This is an example of lightbox in action:
http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/
http://jsfiddle.net/txchou/GBmTL/

This is how to close the window:

```
window.parent.$.prettyPhoto.close();
```